# How do I integrate VisualSVN into Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, svn, integration, visualsvn

I have an existing setup of Visual Studio 2008 with VisualSVN integrated into the IDE.  I have installed and am testing out Visual Studio 2010.  How do I integrate VisualSVN into 2010?  Can I import my existing settings?  I was issued a laptop with all of this setup for me but now we're gonna upgrade to 2010 soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is rerun the VisualSVN installer.  Version 1.7.6 has "experimental" support for VS2010 which I'm told works just fine.  Version 2.0.1 claims complete support.

Comment: If VisualSVN 2.0.1+ was installed before VS2010, you need to "Change" the setup of VisualSVN, not just "Repair" it, since the "Integrate with VS2010" checkbox won't be set.

Answer (score 1):

Same as for VS2008 - though you will, of course, need a version of VisualSVN that supports VS2010. Recent ones do.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try [RocketSVN by Axosoft](http://www.axosoft.com/rocketsvn).  I've been using it for a couple of months now in VS2008 (currently a free beta), I've been pretty happy with it.